# ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR Too many connections Error using Knex

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, stress-testing

I am trying to implement a Node.js application that would allow large amount of concurrent users to insert data to database. I am using Knex to handle database connections. My purpose is to allow server to asynchronously handle million requests from million users. I'm using MySQL NDB Cluster 7.5. Currently I am using ab test tool to stress test the app but I am stuck with following error:

```
ab -p 100.json -T application/json -c 1000 -n 1000 http://34.242.xxx.xxx:3000/insert
Benchmarking 34.242.xxx.xxx (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

From server I find following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
goofy_noyce.1.f7o2c2dp6sb8@ip-172-31-xxx-xxx
```

This is code I am using:

```
const knex = require('knex')(require('../knexfile.js')

const insertData = function (tableName, timestamp, deviceId, data) {
  debug('insert');
  knex(tableName).insert({
timestamp,
deviceId,
data,
 })
.catch(err => debug(`error: ${err}`))
.then((dataid) => {
  debug(`Inserted with id: ${dataid}`);
    });
};

....

insertToDb(req.body.tableName, req.body.timestamp, req.body.deviceId, req.body.data);
res.status(201).json({ success: true });
```

This is knexfile:

```
const config = require('./config/config');

module.exports = {

production: {
client: 'mysql',
connection: {
  host: config.mysql_ip,
  database: config.mysql_database,
  user: config.mysql_user,
  password: config.mysql_pass,
},
pool: {
  min: 2,
  max: 10,
},
  },

};
```

Comment: What does MySQL query `SELECT @@max_connections` output?

Comment: It can also be the case there is a max connection limit on your user within MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Hello, max connection outputs 151. My purpose is to allow server to asynchronously handle million requests from million users.

Comment: I'm using MySQL NDB Cluster 7.5

Comment: MySQL NDB Cluster 7.5  On one server or multiple servers?  "MySQL Cluster delivered 1 billion queries per minute (17.6 million queries per second), scaled-out across 8 x commodity Intel x86 server nodes" source https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-cluster-7.2-ga.html .. That article version is older then yours assuming MySQL cluster 7.5 performs the same.. You likely need multiple servers within the cluster to get million(s) requests per second performance

Comment: My current setup has one sql node, one management node and two data nodes. All on different machines in AWS EC2

Comment: The MySQL Server is limited to 151 connections in the default setup. You can configure this higher but that also requires raising some OS limits on open files.

Comment: There is also a native Java Script API for NDB where you can probably handle a lot more simultaneous activity compared to when you connect to a MySQL Server